# Leaflet/OSM Map won't work on my website, why?

Tags: wordpress, leaflet, openstreetmap

Someone on stackoverflow tried to helped me implement an OSM on my website. The code snippit runs fine here, but nothing will display on my website page, please see www.livehazards.com/sidebar-test. Does anyone know what the problem is. Thanks

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-M2wvCLH6DSRazYeZRIm1JnYyh22purTM+FDB5CsyxtQJYeKq83arPe5wgbNmcFXGqiSH2XR8dT/fJISVA1r/zQ=="
   crossorigin=""/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-lInM/apFSqyy1o6s89K4iQUKg6ppXEgsVxT35HbzUupEVRh2Eu9Wdl4tHj7dZO0s1uvplcYGmt3498TtHq+log=="
   crossorigin=""></script>
<style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #mapid { position:absolute; top:0%; bottom:0%; left:0%; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='mapid'></div>
<script>
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    maxZoom: 18,
});.addTo(mymap);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code contains an unneeded semicolon that causes the error:

```
});.addTo(mymap)
```

It should be:

```
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: Good work! Removing that single syntax error produces a correct page: https://plnkr.co/edit/I9YeG6JeJyTmZsX9tukP?p=preview